# How to automate permissions for AWS s3 bucket objects

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto

I have an s3 bucket that multiple accounts are putting objects in.   I'd like the account that owns the bucket to also own these files.

The script uses boto3 to name and put the object so Would I set permissions in this script?
Or is there an s3 policy that can force ownership on new files?
I'd prefer a bucket policy but I am doubtful it's possible. 
The file name is

> "account# and the date.json"

```
account_id = (boto3.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account'])
s3.Object('S3bucketname', account_id + "_" + date_fmt + ".json").put(Body=json.dumps(iplist))
```

edit:   I should add,  The process that is trying to read from this bucket which has the objects has a role associated with it so I'm assuming my principal would be

> arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID_of_bucket:role/ROLENAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 boto3.resource('s3').ObjectAcl('S3BUCKETNAME', account_id + "_" + date_fmt + ".json").put(ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')
```

The above will give the bucket owner full control of any objects created and put into the bucket by the lambda job with this name format.

Comment: Similar answer using different syntax: `boto3.client('s3').put_bucket_acl(Bucket=bucket, ACL='bucket-owner-full-control')`

Comment: In case you use upload_object, you could also use: `s3_client.upload_fileobj(obj, bucket, filename, ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'})`

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are asking how to enforce `bucket-owner-full-control` on any objects copied into the bucket.

From [S3 Bucket Owner Access](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/), you could use a policy like this:

```
{
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":{"AWS":"111111111111"},
      "Action":"s3:PutObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    },
    {
      "Effect":"Deny",
      "Principal":{"AWS":"111111111111"},
      "Action":"s3:PutObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {"s3:x-amz-acl":"bucket-owner-full-control"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The first part is where access to the bucket is granted. The second part says "Not allowed if `bucket-owner-full-control` was not specified".

When the other accounts are copying files to that bucket, they should specify the `bucket-owner-full-control` ACL. (I know how to do that with a boto3 client, but not with a boto3 resource.)

Comment: That is correct, I'm looking for a way to give full control to the bucket owner using boto3.
Is there a resource I can add to  

s3.Object('S3bucketname', account_id + "_" + date_fmt + ".json").put(Body=json.dumps(iplist)  that would give the bucket owner full control of the object ?

Comment: object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl('s3BUCKETNAME','*')
    object_acl.put(
      ACL="bucket-owner-full-control")


That seems like it should work, but I am getting a key error.

Comment: Your Key is `*`. That is not an allowed filename. (Key = filename)

Comment: Got it.   WIll post a solution below  Thank you